# GAE flush memcache with go

Tags: google-app-engine, go

Are there any docs on how to flush the google app engine memcache using Go?

I can see flush_all() in the python docs https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The memcache go code lists a [flush function](http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/appengine-go/appengine/memcache#Flush), which is not listed in the official docs. I suspect it works and is just undocumented.